# split URL and get value

Tags: c#

How to split a url into an array and take the 7th value. I want to get the value 'premium'

```
https://www.YouMe.com/qwert/rest/services/EEE/premium/Server/export
```

Something like?

```
string[] splitURL = l.URL.Split('/',7);
```

Comment: How is everyone missing that arrays start with index 0? If you want the 7th item, you need to access index 6...

Comment: Nope @germi `[0]="https:"`, `[1]=""`, `[2]="www.YouMe.com"`, `[3]="qwert"`, `[4]="rest"`, `[5]="services"`, `[6]="EEE"`, `[7]="premium"`, `[8]="Server"` and `[9]="export"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Split()`:

```
String source = "https://www.YouMe.com/qwert/rest/services/EEE/premium/Server/export";

String result = source.Split(new Char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[6];
```

you have to process "//" (do not count *empty entries*); another issue is that `Split` returns an *array* - and you have to get the 7th item: `[6]` (arrays are *zero-based*)

Comment: Sir.., your query will gives output as `"Server"` you have to use `[6]` instead for `[7]`

Comment: @un-lucky: Thank you, I see: arrays are *zero-based* so `[6]` is the right index

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right way, [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) will help you, do something like the following to achieve the target.

```
 string url = "https://www.YouMe.com/qwert/rest/services/EEE/premium/Server/export";
  var reqValue= url.Split('/')[7];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
"https://www.YouMe.com/qwert/rest/services/EEE/premium/Server/export".Split('\/')[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string url = "https://www.YouMe.com/qwert/rest/services/EEE/premium/Server/export";

var val= url.Split('/')[7];
```